# What curly braces inside a function call mean in C?

Tags: c, curly-braces, compound-literals

I tried to solve exercise 1-24 in K&R C book in which you have to create a program which can detect basic syntax errors (unbalanced parentheses, brackets and so on). I ran some tests to debug it on C source files scattered on my system. 
My program detected an error when it met this line in a file :

```
av_opt_set_q  (abuffer_ctx, "time_base", (AVRational ){ 1, INPUT_SAMPLERATE }, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
```

I made the assumption that, every time a regular curly bracket is encountered (outside comments, double quotes), parentheses and brackets must be balanced. This is not true as this error showed. Unfortunately I cannot find what it means. Thanks for your help.

Comment: K&R is too old to properly teach standard C. Compound literals were introduced in the year 1999. Consider getting a book which isn't older than 20 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
 (AVRational ){ 1, INPUT_SAMPLERATE }
```

is a [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals). Check more about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

From the `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed
>   list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

That said, I do not see how the braces are not balanced here. This is a valid syntax and your tool should consider this while making decision.

Comment: Thanks @bath, Added one more.

Comment: braces are balanced here. What I meant is when "{" or "}" is encountered "(", ")" and "[" ,]" must be balanced. That was just a guess.

Comment: Some older syntax highlighting tools like `vim` are confused by the presence of curly braces within round parentheses `({})`. It will flag all such opening braces as an error. I don't know whether the current version of `vim` fixes this, but the one I'm using still has this problem. For me, it's just a nuisance; for someone not as versed in C syntax, it must be freaking them out.